# Change Nginx root directory to workspace folder path

Tags: nginx

**Issue**

I installed Nginx with brew on Mac OSX. Then I modified /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf as below and got a server 500 error:

```
server {
    listen       666;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /Users/username/Desktop/workspace/projectname/dist;
    location / {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

**What I tried**

I knew that brew install default root is /usr/local/var/www so I was able to get it working by paste dist folder into /usr/local/var/www and update Nginx config like this:

```
server {
    listen       666;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /usr/local/var/www/dist;
    location / {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

**Other issue**

Even after I paste dist folder into /usr/local/var/www I still got 500 error by updating root like the followings:

```
root /dist
root dist
root ./dist
```

Why does default

```
root index.html
```

gets displayed when I first run Nginx ? but I have to specify my dist folder with full path like /usr/local/var/www/dist ? Can someone please explain.

**Goal**

I want to be able to change root directory to my dist folder in workspace so I don't need to paste the dist folder into /usr/local/var/www every time after I rebuild.

Comment: Does nginx have permission to access that directory?

Comment: @Rob you maybe right, II'll look for other posts on this issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume permissions is the problem. nginx runs as user "www-data" unless you change it. Your directories and files need to allow that user and have their directories set as 755 and the files set to 644.